# How can I refresh Gallery Media to show new files in GridView?

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview, video, camera

I have an activity with 3 fragments:

1. Videos
2. Camera
3. Images

I want to show new recorded videos to be updated on my gridview, how can I achieve this result?

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {

public Cursor cursor;
public int columnIndex;
String VideoPath;
View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_videos, container, false);
    getVideos();
    return view;
}

public void getVideos(){
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails._ID};
    cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
             MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID);
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails._ID);
    GridView VideoImages = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.VideoGrid1);
    VideoImages.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getActivity()));
    VideoImages.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String[] VideoData = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
            cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, VideoData, null,
                    null,
                    null);
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            VideoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()`. This will update the grid elements. Change `adapter` to your `gridview adapter name`.

Comment: I tried it but no success, is there any other method ?